# transforming XML (formerly KML) using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, kml

Hi I'm trying to use the w3schools XSLT Tryit editor to transform a KML file (saved as an XML file), but I can't seem to get it working. Here is a snippet of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
 <Document>
  <name>Bnsf RR cut</name>
  <open>1</open>
  <Style>
   <ListStyle>
    <ItemIcon>
     <href>kmzicon.png</href>
    </ItemIcon>
   </ListStyle>
  </Style>
  <Folder>
   <name>11/10/11 8:17:20 AM</name>
   <Placemark>
    <name>Track</name>
   </Placemark>
  </Folder>
  <Placemark>
   <name>Gray Mesa</name>
   <description><![CDATA[<img width="800" src="1.jpg"/>]]></description>
   <Point>
    <coordinates>-106.493097,34.446357,1692.000000</coordinates>
   </Point>
  </Placemark>
 </Document>
</kml>
```

And my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="Document/Placemark">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I remove the kml tags in the XML code it works fine, but I would rather try and automate this and not have to delete code from numerous XMLs. I've tried adding "kml" to my XSLT code "/kml/Document/Placemark"> but that is not working. Thank you!

What I would like my transformed XML to look like:

```
 <Document> 
  <Placemark>
   <name>Gray Mesa</name>
   <description><![CDATA[<img width="800" src="1.jpg"/>]]></description>
   <Point>
    <coordinates>-106.493097,34.446357,1692.000000</coordinates>
   </Point>
  </Placemark>
 </Document>
```

I think this will work for my purpose.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="kml:kml/kml:Document/kml:Placemark">
     <name><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="kml:name"/></name>
     <description><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="kml:description"/></description>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
```

Each name and description tag includes this however: xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
I can just concatenate that with an Access query though. I do get an error when I try to import into Access though. It says I need a root folder since I only have numerous name and description tags. Is there any way to add a  tag using the XSL. Thank you very much. Sorry for the messy question that I keep editing.

Comment: I think the issue is with the namespace declarations. I don't have a solution for this issue yet, but anecdotally, if you change your loop to be "kml/Document/Placemark" and remove the namespace declarations from the <kml> element, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tim C is correct about the namespaces, but I'd like to add that XSLT is declarative language so usually when I see for-each in stylesheets it can be replace by something more fitting the language. So I would using the following code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="kml:kml/kml:Document/kml:Placemark"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="kml:Placemark">
         <xsl:value-of select="kml:name"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="kml:description"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm trying to import the transformed XML into Access but it is not working. I am getting incorrect syntax errors. The newly transformed XML is just one long line of code: Top of council spring<img width="800" src="38.jpg"/>....  Is there any way to keep the <name> and <description> tags in the new XML? I am trying to use TransformXML method in Access to extract only the name and description since there is a lot of extra code in the original KML file that I don't want. Thank you. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Change the output method to xml, then use
         <xsl:copy-of select="kml:name"/>
         <description><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="kml:description"/></description>

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. I have posted a solution that I can use. Is there a simple way to have the XSL add a root folder? Or just have the XSL keep the root <Document> tag?

Comment: You just surround the name and description with the tag you want:
<root>
     <xsl:value-of select="kml:name"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="kml:description"/>
</root>
Or create template for kml:Document, and create the root node there.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in your XML there is a default namespace

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" ...
```

In XPath 1.0, you must specify a prefix for each namespace you want to use. A path like **Document/Placemark** will only select **Placemark** elements in no namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="kml:kml/kml:Document/kml:Placemark">
         <xsl:value-of select="kml:name"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="kml:description"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also not that doing `<xsl:template match="/">` matches the document element, which is not the same thing as the root element of the document **kml**.

Here is a good article about default namespaces: http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/36

Note that you might want to do this, to output the CDATA of description

```
<xsl:value-of select="kml:description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If its **just placemarks** in the Kml that your dealing with i would  recommend **KMLCSV Converter**. (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kmlcsv/)

**It wont work on lines or polygons though.**

Thanks

Shane